# Link not going back to home page

Tags: html

I have researched this to death including on this page. My index page is outside my html folder and when I hit the nav link it will not take me back home(index page). I have seen a few post on here regarding this situation, see below:

There are also two special directory names: . and ..:

> . means "current directory"
>
> .. means "parent directory"

but I have tried several see below for examples that I have tried. The index page is on/in the root directory (folder), all the other nav links work as they are in the html folder and they are up one level.

I have tried:

```
<a href="./index.html">Index</a>
<a href="/index.html">Index</a>
<a href="index.html">Index</a>
<a href="../index.html">Index</a>
```

Out of desperation I have tried several things I knew would not work, I would really appreciate your assistance in this matter.

littleone

Comment: Show your directory structure.

Comment: Check this link help you http://way2tutorial.com/html/html_subdirectory_link.php

Comment: where does the link take you? or what error do you recieve?

Comment: @user1153551 I think that the example in that page is misleading. The site structure showed there shows an `/html` folder at the same level of the `/css` and `/javascript` folders, and this is not necessarily the case. Usually your HTML files are at the same level of `/css` and `/javascript` and not inside an `/html` folder. Don't know about you but I wouldn't trust that example. PS. For a second I thought it was W3Schools.com :p

Comment: this is true <a href="../index.html">Index</a>

Comment: @ricardozea no no you understand wrong this is example of tutorial site structure to html tutorial put into `html/` , css tutorial put into `css/` and javascript tutorial put into `javascript/` directory. its show you directory structure not show you one html page have and that html page css and js define seprate folder.

Comment: Structure: Marilyn Folder - containing

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the safest way is using

```
<a href="/">index</a>
```

This will move the user to the root directory no matter in which directory the user currently is.

It's quite short which can be helpful too. In most cases you can omit `index.html` because the server uses this file automatically if you visit a directory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no web server specialist, but I'm sure you're saving your `index.html` in the incorrect location.

Your `/html` folder is your **ROOT** folder, anything outside of it isn't accessible via a URL. I'm sure there are ways to override that, but I have never seen anyone do this even in the most complex projects I've worked in.

For example, your site `www.yoursite.com` is located in the `/html` of your server. So if you have your `index.html` file outside of that folder, that file can't be accessed or served at all.

The common sense solution is to move your `index.html` file to the `/html` folder. When you do this you can then use a slash in your `href`, like so:

```
<a href="/">Index</a>
```

Comment: Structure: Marilyn Folder - containing index.html, html folder, images folder, resume folder, stylesheets folder, certificates folder. I order for the circle to be complete and for the nav index link to work does the index.html have to be inside and outside the html folder. I realize that I could fix this and just put the index.html in the html folder but we were not taught that way and I have to fix it and make it work this way. Therefore I guess my question is now if I am using this as a code                       <a href="./html/index.html">Index</a> would it have to be in the html folder.